# Unable to run eslint in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, eslint

I'm trying to set up eslint on my Next.js project. I followed the guide here https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/eslint

When I run `yarn lint`, I receive the error `error - ESLint must be installed`.

In my "devDependencies" in package.json, I have the following:

```
"eslint": "^8.0.1",
"eslint-config-next": "11.1.2"
```

I tried running `yarn add --dev eslint`, but I still receive the same error after running the lint command.

Edit:
This is an existing project. Was created with `yarn create next-app`.
Versions for next and react below

```
"next": "^11.1.2",
"react": "^17.0.2"
```

Node v14.18.1

Comment: Can you provide a little more information about your environment/setup? What version of Next, is this a brand new project or existing? How was it created?

Comment: Updated with versions, @Ben

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ESLint v8 introduced [breaking changes](https://eslint.org/docs/8.0.0/user-guide/migrating-to-8.0.0#the-lib-entrypoint-has-been-removed) that impact compatibility with Next.  Downgrading to 7.32.0 seems to [work](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/29829) for [most people](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/29770).

The Next team is currently [working on](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/29865) adding v8 support.

Comment: Yes. v7.32.0 usable.